# unable to click span #id in div without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below HTML structure

```
<div style="position:relative; width:500px; top:50px; letter-spacing:3px; width:650px; margin:auto; font-size:16px;">
<span id ='Alist' style='cursor:pointer;'>A</span>
<span id ='Blist' style='cursor:pointer;'>B</span>
<span id='Clist' style='cursor:pointer;'>C</span>
<span id='Dlist' style='cursor:pointer;'>D</span>
<span id='Elist' style='cursor:pointer;'>E</span>
..
..
..
</div>
```

clicking on the respective alphabet would bring out a list of names.

Javascript code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#Alist').on('click', function() {$('#A').show();});
$('#Blist').on('click', function() {$('#B').show();});
$('#Clist').click(function() {$('#C').show();});
$('#Dlist').click(function() {$('#D').show();});
$('#Elist').click(function() {$('#E').show();});
});
```

I tried

```
.on / .click as you can see on #Alist and #Blist
```

When I click "A" none of the other alphabets are clickable.  If I have to refresh the page to click the next alphabet.

What is wrong here?
Pls let me know if you require anything is not clear.

Comment: Can you please provide your entire Html / JS. Because so far it seems to be fine: http://jsfiddle.net/xsv5kd98/1

Comment: It does work here: http://jsfiddle.net/6kdywgud/ . Feel free to update the fiddle, so that it reflects your situation.

Comment: It seems like `#A` (or another one) element is above the other links (eg. absolutely positioned and have higher z-index).

Comment: Yep that could be, we'll see once he added the other html stuff and their styles

Comment: @panther I think you are correct, can you put it as an answer?

Comment: @X10nD: it was just a tip. I put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements `#A, #B`, etc. are floated or positioned. Because of higher `z-index` they are above links and links aren't clickable.